# Xcode LLDB: How do I set a conditional breakpoint based on the this pointer?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb, conditional-breakpoint

I have a c++ application and am trying to debug it under Xcode using LLDB. I would like to stop inside a member function, but only when the this pointer matches a specific instance.

I have tried setting a conditional in the breakpoint with the following expression:

```
this == 0x12345
```

But I repeatedly get the following error:

```
error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a nonstatic member function
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

When paused at that breakpoint, I cannot enter the above expression in the debugger console either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling your application using any optimization flags? Or, if you're using Cmake, is your build type "Release with Debug Info"?

Comment: @Dan this is a debug build, all optimization flags are off and we are generating debugging symbols.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the issue is with `this`. With Objective-C, the equivalent is `self`.

So, the condition can be set easily with:

```
self == 0x12345
```

Here's an example where the debugger stops successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however `this` and `self` are different language constructs. As noted above, using `this` instead of `self` in your example does not work. (Note that I am debugging a c++ struct here, so `self` does not exist in the debugging context.)